# Webrat looking for an action it does not need

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, webrat

### Scenario

I have a controller with two actions only - `:create` and `:delete`. Where the create action is defined thus:

```
def create
  # some code...
  if @thing.save
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "Successfully created."
  else
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "Successfully deleted."
  end
end
```

I link to the action using...

```
<%= link_to "Become a friend", things_path(...), :method => :post %>
```

...in the view.

### Problem

This works fine as I interact with the app in my browser. However, I wish to test this functionality using RSpec integration testing using Webrat's helper method - `click_link "Become a friend"` - which I think is correct. But I get this error

```
Failure/Error: click_link "I like Person-1's taste"
AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
  The action 'index' could not be found for ThingsController
```

I can create an empty index action in the Things controller but this would violate the [KISS Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

### Questions

How can I workaround/fix this? And are there any best practices for cases like this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that :method => :post makes rails create a form which is then submitted when you click the link. This only works with javascript enabled which webrat does not support out of the box. Have a look at https://github.com/brynary/webrat/wiki and try to get the test running with selenium. As selenium actually uses a real browser, your specs should run.

Comment: Even with Selenium, the test still fails with the same error. I am not doing any `remote` calls here - which would require javascript.